# MongoDB driver for nodejs 3.0.x does not reconnect automatically

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I was working with the driver 2.2.34 of MongoDB against Mongo 2 and 3.6 and it worked perfectly. My application tries to insert some data and throw an error if an error occur. In my tests I stop the database server to force errors and connect again a bit later. It worked as expected:

- [connection lost]
- try to insert data
- buffer it
- try to insert data
- throw error
- [MongoDB Up]
- recover automatically
- try to insert data -> OK!

However, looks like driver 3.0.2 is unable to recover from the connection lost, which worked fine in the 2.2.34. Next you can see the [simplified] piece of code.

Do you know what's wrong?

```
async connect() {
   let database = await MongoClient.connect('database-url', {bufferMaxEntries:1});
   this.db = database.db('my-database-name')
}

[...]

async saveData(myData) {
    [...]
    try {
       result = await this.db.collection("collection").insertOne(myData.data);
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error();
    }
}
```